# Theme modification from Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I´m currently modifying the appearence of my Shopify website but I´m having some troubles. I wanted to get rid of the space between the two sections of pictures that you can see in the image below:

[image: 1]

I did actually managed to do it but with these modifications something else got modified as well. What I did was to modify the value of

```
 @include at-query($min, $large) {
 margin:35px;
```

in the code below from 35 px to -16px. (The code belongs to the theme.scss.liquid file)

```
/*================ Theme-specific partials ================*/
/*================ Theme specific global styles ================*/
hr {
border-width: $borderWidthHeader 0 0 0;
width: 50px;
}

.hr--small {
 @extend hr;
 margin: 20px auto;
}

 .hr--medium {
 @extend hr;
 margin: 35px auto;

@include at-query($min, $large) {
 margin: -16px auto;
}
}

.hr--large {
 @extend hr;
 margin: ($gutter * 2) auto;
 }

.hr--left {
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 }
```

The problem is that, since that part of the code addresses the entire style of the web, I also reduced the margins of other sections as you can see in the picture below:

[image: 2]

You can see now that the distance with the "Featured products" text has been also reduced, and this is something that I would like to avoid.

My question is, do you know how could I keep the change I did only to be effective to remove the gap of the 2 sections of pictures in the image and nothing else?

Thank you

Comment: Could you include the HTML where you embedded/added your image? :) You could add a new style, e.g. ".some_class {}" in your CSS to specifically target only the image.

Comment: I can´t find the code where that is contained, I did through the Shopify UI ... I know "the theory" of what I need to do, but don´t know how to implement it, I have no experience with Javascript

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't used Shopify before but this website (https://docs.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/choosing-an-editor) indicates that you can edit both the HTML and CSS directly. I would suggest that you use either Chrome or Firefox to view your page and then right-click on the image and select "Inspect Element". The Inspector allows you to see easily what class rules the image is subjected to.